# Quantity input box missing from simple product pages

Tags: template, xml, simple-product, quantity

The quantity input box is missing from simple product pages. When I turn on template hinting, I'm seeing far more blocks in the config product than in the simple.

For example, I get the following blocks in config (which contain product quantity).

```
frontend/default/site/template/catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml
frontend/default/site/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml
frontend/default/site/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml
frontend/default/site/template/page/js/calendar.phtml
```

But in simple I see none of these blocks outputted in templated hints.

I don't think it's an issue with xml as I have tested the base catalog.xml and still same missing quantity box.  Any insight would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

I originally thought it was something in the options.phtml file, but again, I'm not quite sure.

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
/* @var $this Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options */
?>

<?php $_options = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getOptions()) ?>
<?php if (count($_options)):?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var optionFileUpload = {
        productForm : $('product_addtocart_form'),
        formAction : '',
        formElements : {},
        upload : function(element){
            this.formElements = this.productForm.select('input', 'select', 'textarea', 'button');
            this.removeRequire(element.readAttribute('id').sub('option_', ''));

            template = '<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" style="width:0; height:0; border:0;"><\/iframe>';

            Element.insert($('option_'+element.readAttribute('id').sub('option_', '')+'_uploaded_file'), {after: template});

            this.formAction = this.productForm.action;

            var baseUrl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/product/upload') ?>';
            var urlExt = 'option_id/'+element.readAttribute('id').sub('option_', '');

            this.productForm.action = parseSidUrl(baseUrl, urlExt);
            this.productForm.target = 'upload_target';
            this.productForm.submit();
            this.productForm.target = '';
            this.productForm.action = this.formAction;
        },
        removeRequire : function(skipElementId){
            for(var i=0; i<this.formElements.length; i++){
                if (this.formElements[i].readAttribute('id') != 'option_'+skipElementId+'_file' && this.formElements[i].type != 'button') {
                    this.formElements[i].disabled='disabled';
                }
            }
        },
        addRequire : function(skipElementId){
            for(var i=0; i<this.formElements.length; i++){
                if (this.formElements[i].readAttribute('name') != 'options_'+skipElementId+'_file' && this.formElements[i].type != 'button') {
                    this.formElements[i].disabled='';
                }
            }
        },
        uploadCallback : function(data){
            this.addRequire(data.optionId);
            $('upload_target').remove();

            if (data.error) {

            } else {
                $('option_'+data.optionId+'_uploaded_file').value = data.fileName;
                $('option_'+data.optionId+'_file').value = '';
                $('option_'+data.optionId+'_file').hide();
                $('option_'+data.optionId+'').hide();
                template = '<div id="option_'+data.optionId+'_file_box"><a href="#"><img src="var/options/'+data.fileName+'" alt=""><\/a><a href="#" onclick="optionFileUpload.removeFile('+data.optionId+')" title="Remove file" \/>Remove file<\/a>';

                Element.insert($('option_'+data.optionId+'_uploaded_file'), {after: template});
            }
        },
        removeFile : function(optionId)
        {
            $('option_'+optionId+'_uploaded_file').value= '';
            $('option_'+optionId+'_file').show();
            $('option_'+optionId+'').show();

            $('option_'+optionId+'_file_box').remove();
        }
    }
    var optionTextCounter = {
        count : function(field,cntfield,maxlimit){
            if (field.value.length > maxlimit){
                field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
            } else {
                cntfield.innerHTML = maxlimit - field.value.length;
            }
        }
    }

    Product.Options = Class.create();
    Product.Options.prototype = {
        initialize : function(config) {
            this.config = config;
            this.reloadPrice();
            document.observe("dom:loaded", this.reloadPrice.bind(this));
        },
        reloadPrice : function() {
            var config = this.config;
            var skipIds = [];
            $$('body .product-custom-option').each(function(element){
                var optionId = 0;
                element.name.sub(/[0-9]+/, function(match){
                    optionId = parseInt(match[0], 10);
                });
                if (config[optionId]) {
                    var configOptions = config[optionId];
                    var curConfig = {price: 0};
                    if (element.type == 'checkbox' || element.type == 'radio') {
                        if (element.checked) {
                            if (typeof configOptions[element.getValue()] != 'undefined') {
                                curConfig = configOptions[element.getValue()];
                            }
                        }
                    } else if(element.hasClassName('datetime-picker') && !skipIds.include(optionId)) {
                        dateSelected = true;
                        $$('.product-custom-option[id^="options_' + optionId + '"]').each(function(dt){
                            if (dt.getValue() == '') {
                                dateSelected = false;
                            }
                        });
                        if (dateSelected) {
                            curConfig = configOptions;
                            skipIds[optionId] = optionId;
                        }
                    } else if(element.type == 'select-one' || element.type == 'select-multiple') {
                        if ('options' in element) {
                            $A(element.options).each(function(selectOption){
                                if ('selected' in selectOption && selectOption.selected) {
                                    if (typeof(configOptions[selectOption.value]) != 'undefined') {
                                        curConfig = configOptions[selectOption.value];
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (element.getValue().strip() != '') {
                            curConfig = configOptions;
                        }
                    }
                    if(element.type == 'select-multiple' && ('options' in element)) {
                        $A(element.options).each(function(selectOption) {
                            if (('selected' in selectOption) && typeof(configOptions[selectOption.value]) != 'undefined') {
                                if (selectOption.selected) {
                                    curConfig = configOptions[selectOption.value];
                                } else {
                                    curConfig = {price: 0};
                                }
                                optionsPrice.addCustomPrices(optionId + '-' + selectOption.value, curConfig);
                                optionsPrice.reload();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // optionsPrice.addCustomPrices(element.id || optionId, curConfig);
                        optionsPrice.reload();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    function validateOptionsCallback(elmId, result) {
        var container = $(elmId).up('ul.options-list');
        if (result == 'failed') {
            container.removeClassName('validation-passed');
            container.addClassName('validation-failed');
        } else {
            container.removeClassName('validation-failed');
            container.addClassName('validation-passed');
        }
    }
    var opConfig = new Product.Options(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    //]]>
    </script>
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <?php $_product = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view')->getProduct(); ?>
    <?php if($_product->getTypeId() == 'simple'){ ?>
        <div class="custom-options-info">
        <!--**************Custom option*************-->
            <?php $heightDecimal = explode(',',$_product->getHeightDecimal()); ?>
            <?php $widthDecimal = explode(',',$_product->getWidthDecimal()); ?>
                <div class="combination-widtth-height">
                    <?php foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $valueCustom) { ?> 
                          <?php if($valueCustom->getTitle() == 'Height'){ ?>
                            <div class="height-option">
                            <label<?php if ($valueCustom->getIsRequire()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($valueCustom->getIsRequire()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo  $this->htmlEscape($valueCustom->getTitle()) ?></label>    
                                    <input id="put-value-height" onkeyup="putValueHeight('options_<?php echo $valueCustom->getId() ?>_text',this.value)"  type="text"  class="input-text<?php echo $valueCustom->getIsRequire() ? ' required-entry' : '' ?> <?php echo $valueCustom->getMaxCharacters() ? ' validate-length maximum-length-'.$valueCustom->getMaxCharacters() : '' ?> product-custom-option" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getDefaultValue()) ?>" />
                                    <select class="input-text product-custom-option" id="put-value-height-decimal" onchange="putValueHeightDecimal('options_<?php echo $valueCustom->getId() ?>_text',this.value)">
                                        <option value="">0</option>  
                                        <?php foreach($heightDecimal as $hgtDec): ?>
                                            <?php $heightDecimalText = explode('/',$hgtDec); ?>
                                            <?php $heightDecimalInt1 = $heightDecimalText[0]; ?>
                                            <?php $heightDecimalInt2 = $heightDecimalText[1]; ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo number_format(round(($heightDecimalInt1 / $heightDecimalInt2),3),3); ?>"><?php echo $hgtDec; ?></option>    
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                <?php }

                                if($valueCustom->getTitle() == 'Width'){ ?>
                                    <div class="width-option">
                                    <label<?php if ($valueCustom->getIsRequire()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($valueCustom->getIsRequire()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo  $this->htmlEscape($valueCustom->getTitle()) ?></label>    
                                    <input id="put-value-width" onkeyup="putValueWidth('options_<?php echo $valueCustom->getId() ?>_text',this.value)"  type="text"  class="input-text<?php echo $valueCustom->getIsRequire() ? ' required-entry' : '' ?> <?php echo $valueCustom->getMaxCharacters() ? ' validate-length maximum-length-'.$valueCustom->getMaxCharacters() : '' ?> product-custom-option" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getDefaultValue()) ?>" />
                                    <select class="input-text product-custom-option" id="put-value-width-decimal" onchange="putValueWidthDecimal('options_<?php echo $valueCustom->getId() ?>_text',this.value)">
                                        <option value="">0</option>  
                                        <?php foreach($widthDecimal as $hgtDec): ?>
                                            <?php $heightDecimalText = explode('/',$hgtDec); ?>
                                            <?php $heightDecimalInt1 = $heightDecimalText[0]; ?>
                                            <?php $heightDecimalInt2 = $heightDecimalText[1]; ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo number_format(round(($heightDecimalInt1 / $heightDecimalInt2),3),3); ?>"><?php echo $hgtDec; ?></option>    
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <?php } ?>
                          </div>
                            <!--**************Custom option*************-->
    <?php foreach($_options as $_option): ?>
        <?php  
            if($i > 1 && $i % 3 == 2){
//                echo '<div class="custom-options-info">';  ?>

            <?php }
//            if($i == 0){
//                echo '<div class="custom-options-first-info">';
//            }
        ?>
        <?php echo $this->getOptionHtml($_option) ?>
        <?php 
//            if($i > 1 && $i % 3 == 1){
//                echo '</div>';
//            }
//            if($i == 1){
//                echo '</div>';
//            }
            ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php 
//        if($i % 3 != 2){
//             echo '</div>';
//        } 
//        if($i == 1){
//             echo '</div>';
//        } 
        ?>
                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <?php if (!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <?php $prodminqty = $_product->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty(); ?>
            <div class="prod_quantity">
                <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity') ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"  value="<?php echo $prodminqty > 0 ? $prodminqty : 1; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            </div>
                        <?php $edge_image = $_product->getEdgeImage() ?>
                <?php if ($_product->getEdgeType() == 1): ?>
                    <div class="edge-link">
                        <a id="edge-box-a"><?php echo $this->__('Outside Edge Image Options'); ?></a>
                    </div>
            <div id='edge-image-none' style='display:none'><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'edge_image/' . $edge_image ?>"/></div>
            <div id="edge-image-parent" class='egde-image-class-parent'>
                    <div class="fancybox-item" id="edge-image" style='display:none'>
                            <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'edge_image/' . $edge_image ?>"/>
                    </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                        jQuery("a#edge-box-a").fancybox({
                            'width': '100%',
                            'height': '100%',
                            'autoScale': true,
                            'transitionIn': 'fade',
                            'transitionOut': 'fade',
                            'type': 'inline',
                            'href': '#edge-image',
                            afterClose: function() {
                                 htmlstart="  <div id='edge-image' class='fancybox-item' style='display:none;'>";
                                 htmlEnd="</div>";
                                jQuery("#edge-image-parent").html(htmlstart+jQuery("#edge-image-none").html()+htmlEnd);
                            }
                        });

                    });
                    </script>

    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <?php foreach($_options as $_option): ?>
        <?php  
            if($i == 0 && strtolower($_option->getTitle()) != 'width' && strtolower($_option->getTitle()) != 'height'){
                echo '<div class="custom-options-info">';
            }
            if($i > 1 && $i % 3 == 2 && strtolower($_option->getTitle()) != 'width' && strtolower($_option->getTitle()) != 'height'){
                echo '<div class="custom-options-info custom-options-info-new">';
            }
//            elseif($i != 0 && $i % 3 == 1){
//                echo '<div class="custom-options-info-new">';
//            }
        ?>
        <?php echo $this->getOptionHtml($_option) ?>
        <?php 
            if($i == 1 && strtolower($_option->getTitle()) != 'width' && strtolower($_option->getTitle()) != 'height'){
                echo '</div>';
            }
            if($i > 1 && $i % 3 == 1 && strtolower($_option->getTitle()) != 'width' && strtolower($_option->getTitle()) != 'height'){
                echo '</div>';
            }

            ?>
    <?php 
    if(strtolower($_option->getTitle()) != 'width' && strtolower($_option->getTitle()) != 'height'){
    $i++;
    } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php if($i % 3 != 1){
             echo '</div>';
        } ?>
    <?php } ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php // Quantity box for config products ?>
<?php $_product = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_view')->getProduct(); ?>
    <?php if($_product->getTypeId() == 'configurable'){ ?>
            <div class="prod_quantity">
                <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Quantity') ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"  value="<?php echo $prodminqty > 0 ? $prodminqty : 1; ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
            </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple product the QTY feild is usually in the addtocart.phtml which is pulled into the view.phtml with the call `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>` I'd reccomend you check if you have the `$this->getChildHtml('addtocart')` call in your themes view.phtml and also check your themes addotcart.phtml file against what is in base/default.

Comment: I was able to make it work with some custom code inside the addtocart.phtml. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you please let me know, what changes you have made for it.